# Multiple Joins with same table in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

In the query below, I am joining table T1 to multiple tables based on same key. I am wondering in this case do I need to specify the conditions

```
 AND a.ds = '2014-12-10'
 AND a.org_id IS NULL
```

for every join ? What is the rationale for not doing this ?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tab1
        PARTITION(ds='2014-12-10')
    SELECT
        a.var1
        , b.var2
        , c.var3
        , d.var4

    FROM T1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 b
        ON a.var1 = settings.var1

        AND a.ds = '2014-12-10'
        AND a.org_id IS NULL

    LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 c
        ON a.var1 = bmid.var1
        AND c.ds = '2014-12-10'

        AND a.ds = '2014-12-10'
        AND a.org_id IS NULL

    LEFT OUTER JOIN T4 d
        ON a.var1 = daa.var1
        AND d.ds = '2014-12-10'

        AND a.ds = '2014-12-10'
        AND a.org_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not. You can simply move those conditions to the "where" clause for the whole query. Check the explain plan it will be the same as what you have currently.

Code example:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tab1
        PARTITION(ds='2014-12-10')
    SELECT
        a.var1
        , b.var2
        , c.var3
        , d.var4
    FROM T1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 b
        ON a.var1 = settings.var1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 c
        ON a.var1 = bmid.var1
        AND c.ds = '2014-12-10'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T4 d
        ON a.var1 = daa.var1
        AND d.ds = '2014-12-10'
    **WHERE
        a.ds = '2014-12-10'
        AND a.org_id IS NULL**
```

Comment: where clause?? are you talking about IN?

Comment: I added a code example above. Here is a link for reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-WHEREClause

Comment: I learnt that using Where is not as efficient as filtering in Join in HIVE. And, I also learnt recently, that if I just use it in the first join, it works. Results will be same as using WHERE Clause.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I found out: There is this concept of PredicatePushDown (which I am not 100% sure off. But it is default in newer versions of Hive). If I set this with hive.optimize.ppd = true; Then I get same performance in the two cases:

I case: conditions are specified in all joins
Results:

-- 24254 Rows loaded to tab1

-- MapReduce Jobs Launched:

-- Job 0: Map: 16  Reduce: 4   Cumulative CPU: 802.6 sec   HDFS Read: 3020743758 HDFS Write: 900057 SUCCESS

-- Job 1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 4.93 sec   HDFS Read: 965541 HDFS Write: 898430 SUCCESS

-- Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 13 minutes 27 seconds 530 msec

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tab1
    blah blah ..
FROM T1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 b
    ON a.var1 = settings.var1

    AND a.ds = '2014-12-10'
    AND a.org_id IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 c
    ON a.var1 = bmid.var1
    AND c.ds = '2014-12-10'

    AND a.ds = '2014-12-10'
    AND a.org_id IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN T4 d
    ON a.var1 = daa.var1
    AND d.ds = '2014-12-10'

    AND a.ds = '2014-12-10'
    AND a.org_id IS NULL
```

II case: conditions are specified in first join only

Results:

-- 24254

-- Job 0: Map: 16  Reduce: 4   Cumulative CPU: 803.35 sec   HDFS Read: 3020743758 HDFS Write: 900057 SUCCESS

-- Job 1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.75 sec   HDFS Read: 965541 HDFS Write: 898429 SUCCESS

-- Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 13 minutes 27 seconds 100 msec

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tab1
    blah blah ..
FROM T1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 b
    ON a.var1 = settings.var1

    AND a.ds = '2014-12-10'
    AND a.org_id IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 c
    ON a.var1 = bmid.var1
    AND c.ds = '2014-12-10'

LEFT OUTER JOIN T4 d
    ON a.var1 = daa.var1
    AND d.ds = '2014-12-10'
```